# Custom SearchBar Android

Tags: android, material-design, searchbar

I have been trying to achieve this type of `SearchBar`in my android app. [search bar android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsoor.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsoor.png) I have tried a list of libraries but it didn't give me the expected result. 
One of the libraries i found to be the closest was this one. [custom search bar by mancj](https://github.com/mancj/MaterialSearchBar)
However, when i tried importing the dependency, (`implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.7.6'`) it gave me an error.

**ERROR**

```
Could not find com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.7.6.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Users/bnotion/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/github/mancj/MaterialSearchBar/0.7.6/MaterialSearchBar-0.7.6.pom
    file:/C:/Users/bnotion/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/github/mancj/MaterialSearchBar/0.7.6/MaterialSearchBar-0.7.6.jar
    file:/C:/Users/bnotion/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/github/mancj/MaterialSearchBar/0.7.6/MaterialSearchBar-0.7.6.pom
    file:/C:/Users/bnotion/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/github/mancj/MaterialSearchBar/0.7.6/MaterialSearchBar-0.7.6.jar
    file:/C:/Users/bnotion/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/github/mancj/MaterialSearchBar/0.7.6/MaterialSearchBar-0.7.6.pom
    file:/C:/Users/bnotion/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/github/mancj/MaterialSearchBar/0.7.6/MaterialSearchBar-0.7.6.jar
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/mancj/MaterialSearchBar/0.7.6/MaterialSearchBar-0.7.6.pom
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/mancj/MaterialSearchBar/0.7.6/MaterialSearchBar-0.7.6.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/mancj/MaterialSearchBar/0.7.6/MaterialSearchBar-0.7.6.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/mancj/MaterialSearchBar/0.7.6/MaterialSearchBar-0.7.6.jar
Required by:
    project :app
```

**GRADLE (app level)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.7.6'
    implementation 'com.shobhitpuri.custombuttons:google-signin:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**GRADLE (project level)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I think there might be an issue with the library import. Is there a way to fix this? 
I also want it that when it clicked, the search query gets activated. Any useful ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Put some codes here to show your effort of researching instead of a screenshot

Comment: please review my code

Comment: post your gradle, it might due to your dependency settings

Comment: please review again

Comment: check your another gradle, is this line added? allprojects {
 repositories {
  ...
  maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
 }
}

Comment: i think it was added. please review again bro.

Comment: can load now right?

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answer mate

Answer (score 2):

In your project level `build.gradle` file, make sure you have `maven` in there, or else you cannot use the library.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think it was added. please review again bro.

Comment: @Benfight add it under allproject not buildscript

Comment: @Benfight dont worry! Peace! Dont forget to mark as answer, thank you!